# Cell height and width of excel file export from Crystal Reports and BI Launch Pad are compressed

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

Both of the cell height and width of excel file export from Crystal Reports and BI Launch Pad are compressed. Is there a way to fix this problem? Thanks.

CR design mode

[image]

Excel output

[image]

CR and BI launch pad preview

[image]

Comment: Is this standard Crystal Reports or Crystal Reports for Enterprise? Can you provide a screenshot of the report in design mode?

Comment: sorry but not understand, what is BI launch pad. are you want export excel of crystal report and want to cell height width same as in preview?

Comment: Hi @Isaac, it's the standard Crystal Reports I believe. I have attached the screen shots of the design mode and the excel output which shows cell height and width are compressed.

Comment: Hi @Ajay2707, BI launch pad is the Business Objects portal from SAP that allows crystal reports to be uploaded, and let end users to run the reports and export into formats such as PDF, excel and word. The preview of both Bi launch pad and crystal reports are in a format like what you see in PDF, I have attached the screen shot in the post.

Comment: What exactly are you exporting? Your Excel screenshot doesn't look anything like your report.

Comment: Sorry @Isaac, I accidentally pasted the wrong excel output. I have just replaced it with the correct one.

Comment: When you export to Excel which option are you using? Microsoft Excel (97-2003), Microsoft Excel (97-2003) Data-Only, or something else?

Comment: Hi @Isaac, I'm using Microsoft Excel Workbook Data-Only option.

Comment: Can you try each of the other Excel related options and see what you get? Also, you can adjust some of the export options from the menu under File > Export > Report Export Options. Maybe there is something in there that is adversely affecting your exported spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks @Isaac. I tried Microsoft Excel (97-2003) with different options, it worked when exporting from Crystal Report and scheduled report in Business Objects. The only issue is when export from Business Objects directly, there is no option to insert Gridline, so the output has no gridline, but I guess it is the best result I could achieve. Thanks for your help.